# AngularStrap datepicker looks odd

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-strap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to use the AngularStrap datepicker in my project by following the directions on the [AngularDart getting started guide](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers#datepickers)
The functionality is fine, but the look is off.
Even without my own stylesheets loaded the look is not what it should be.
These 2 screenshots should clarify the issue:

How it should look:

[image: how it should look]

How it actually looks:

[image]

The application is scaffolded with yeoman.io

The bower.json config:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.14",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.14",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.14",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.14",
    "angular-route": "1.2.14",
    "moment": "~2.5.1",
    "angular-strap": "~2.0.0",
    "angular-motion": "~0.3.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.14",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.14"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.14"
  }
}
```

The relevant index.html snippets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-motion/dist/angular-motion.min.css" />
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
....
<script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>

<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

The datepicker input tag in html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" data-start-view="2" bs-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add the following styles:

```
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  button {
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
  }
  tbody {
    height: 180px;
  }
  tbody button {
    padding: 6px;
  }
  &.datepicker-mode-1, &.datepicker-mode-2 {
    tbody button {
      height: 65px;
    }
  }
}

.timepicker.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0 4px;
  button {
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
  }
  tbody button {
    padding: 6px;
  }
}
```

Note that this is less/sass formatted. If you need straight css, convert it first [here](http://less2css.org/).

Here is an angular-strap issue in which mgcrea supplies this needed css: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/398.

Essentially, you just need to remove button borders and outlines and add some spacing and it'll look just like on the angular-strap page.

Comment: additionally, it solves a width issue when using grid! :)

Comment: Looks like the author has published this (and other similar styles bridging between `angular-strap` and `bootstrap`) as a separate project called `bootstrap-additions`: https://github.com/mgcrea/bootstrap-additions